# Why is it so hard to ping my own Server?

Tags: javascript

I got this piece of cake function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Example.html',
    DataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    success: function (){
        alert ('Yes');
    },
    error: function (){
        alert ('No');
    }
});
```

This function, works just fine, BUT ONLY FOR THE VERY FIRST TIME), from the second time on, the function sends the following error to Chrome:

GET http://MyServer.com/Example.html?_=1406469092100 net::ERR_FAILED

The same situation happens equally with this second JS option:

```
function doesConnectionExist() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "http://www.example.com/Example.html";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);

    try {
        xhr.send();
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
             alert ('Yes');
        } else {
             alert ('No');
        }
    } catch (e) {
         alert ('No');
    }
}
```

1) In the Ajax scenario I just indicate cache: "false"!

2) In the JavaScript scenario I am using random arguments to avoid cache!

Is there anything I am missing? in the Server side??

Please help...

Comment: Your second function always returns false, because the status is not ready immediately after calling send - you need to wait for the request to complete

Comment: and never alert in a function you want to call repeatedly. instead use `window.console&&console.log("whatever");`

Comment: @Eric it's a synchronous request.

Comment: @Pointy - does not look sync to me

Comment: Isn't that the third param to open?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a server problem? I have created a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/Yc3ub/) and it seems to work like it should. I wrapped your $.ajax method in a `ping` function and run it 3 times fetching a jsfiddle resource.

```
function ping(i) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/img/logo.png',
    success: function () {
        screen.log({text: 'attempt #'+(i+1)+ ' Yes', timed: +i, clear: 'no'});
    },
    error: function (d){
        screen.log({text: 'attempt #'+(i+1)+ ' Nope', timed: +i, clear: 'no'});
    }
  });
}
```

See the already mentioned [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/Yc3ub/) for output

**Note**: in your second code snippet your supply `false` as the third paramater to the `open` method, which means `asynchronous = false`, so the XHR there is synchronous. The `cache: false` parameter in the first snippet appends a random reuqeststring to the request. This prevents the browser from caching the fetched resource. I suppose it's not really necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of try an error I found the Answer....dedicated for those guys who are facing the same problem I did:

In my case this was not a common Web Page, it was an "Offline Web Page" with a Manifest File in it.

Simply in the section "NETWORK" of the manifest file included the file "Example.html" and that's it.

That's all folks!

Comment: So, a server problem after all.